# javascript中のfunctionが実行されない

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, slim

Ruby on Railsで開発しています。
viewはslimで作成していて、AdminLTEのテーブルのデザインを適用しようと思ってます。
その中にページングなどを実行するためのjavascriptコードがありますが、
それが実行されないんです。
javascriptのところのコード下記の通りです。

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#example1").DataTable();
  });
</script>
```

自分のslimコードです。

```
javascript:
  alert('Slim supports embedded javascript!11')
  $(function () {
    alert('Slim supports embedded javascript!22')
  $("#example1").DataTable();
});
```

自分のコードにはjavascriptの動作確認のため、alertを追加しました。
alertが2個ありますが、〜11になっているところは実行されますが、
〜22と書いてあるところは実行されていません。
あと、一回実行したページから「ページのソース表示」でのhtmlコードでも特に違いはありませんでした。
なので、slim化には問題はなさそうですが。。。
あのコードを実行できる方法を教えてください。

Comment: ブラウザの開発者ツールでJavascriptコンソールに何かエラーが出ていませんか？

Comment: 他のところでのエラーで実行されなかっただけでした。

Answer (score 1):

ステートメントの区切りにセミコロンが無いためエラーになってませんか？

```
alert('Slim supports embedded javascript!11');
$(function () {
    alert('Slim supports embedded javascript!22');
    $("#example1").DataTable();
});
```